# drone cli can not execute

Tags: cicd, drone.io

I can't use the drone cli, it just told me:

`Stage '' not found in build file : resource not found`

What the problem is?

And it also told me:

```
proto: duplicate proto type registered: PluginSpec
proto: duplicate proto type registered: PluginPrivilege
```

When I used `drone` command

Is this a problem?

Here is my .drone.yml

```
kind: pipeline
type: exec
name: test

steps:
  - name: echo
    commands:
      - echo "hello world"
```

Comment: Downgrading to 1.5.0 fixed this for me.

Comment: What was your solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss the `--pipeline test` option.

Also if you use another Docker daemon, you have to set the `DOCKER_HOST` before you run drone local execution.

For colima:

```bash
export DOCKER_HOST="unix://${HOME}/.colima/default/docker.sock"
drone exec --trusted --pipeline test
```

Answer (score -4):

first you need to install cli:

```
curl -L https://github.com/harness/drone-cli/releases/latest/download/drone_linux_amd64.tar.gz | tar zx
sudo install -t /usr/local/bin drone
```

Then you need to provide the CLI tools with the server addresses and your personal authorization token. You can find your authorization token in your Drone account settings (click your Avatar in the user Drone Web interface),
and configure your Drone server address:

```
export DRONE_SERVER=http://drone.mycompany.com
export DRONE_TOKEN=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9...
```

After that, you`ll see the Drone CLI. Check the CLI:

```
drone info
```